# Ruby ARGV array search

Tags: ruby, argv

I am having some issues searching for what options have been passed in the ARGV. I have,

```
if ARGV.include? '-v' == true
    puts "Do junk"
else
    puts "Nope"
end
```

This seems like a shockingly simple thing but I always get "Nope" either when I place "-v" or when I do not. Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: how you are running `.rb` file?

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps it first evaluates `'v' == true`, which yields `false`. Then, `ARGV.include? false` which also yields `false`, hence it executes the `else`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Your are right absolutely..

Comment: Arup: I am running by entering "ruby <filename> <options>" Options can come before the file name as well and I am sorting all of that out before this point. My issue was that I specified "true". I believe I am having one of those mornings...

Comment: Why are you searching ARGV for options? Don't reinvent wheels, instead use the standard library's [OptionParser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) class, which is made for this.

Comment: @joerdie no needed that information, as I got your problem :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don know if it's your problem, but you don't need the `== true`.

```
if ARGV.include? '-v'
  puts "Do junk"
else
  puts "Nope"
end
```

The [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) method returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: That actually solved the issue. Though some of the other answers were also helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you searching ARGV for options? Use the standard library's [OptionParser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) class, which is made for this.

```
require 'optparse'
require 'pp'

options = {}
OptionParser.new { |opt|
  opt.on('-v', '--verbose', 'Be verbose') { |o| options[:verbose] = o }
}.parse!

pp options
```

Save that, and run it with something like: `ruby test.rb -v` or `ruby test.rb --verbose` and you'll see:

```
{:verbose=>true}
```

Run it with `ruby test.rb -h` or `ruby test.rb --help` and you'll see:

```
Usage: test [options]
    -v, --verbose                    Be verbose
```

OptionParser has all sorts of nice (and intelligent) tricks for setting booleans, required parameters, coercing values so you can get multiple values for a parameter returned as an array, etc. And, notice that it created the help for me, including using `-h` or `--help` for the flag.

Look at the examples in the documentation for additional ideas of what it can do.

Answer (score 2):

This is a precedence problem. Write as'

```
if ARGV.include?('-v') == true
  puts "Do junk"
else
  puts "Nope"
end
```

In your case `if ARGV.include? '-v' == true` has been interpreted as `if ARGV.include? 
('-v' == true)`. Now `'-v' == true` returns `false`, and `false` is not included in your `ARGV` array, so `if` evaluates as `false`, and `else` part is getting executed.

Better to write as

```
if ARGV.include? '-v'
  puts "Do junk"
else
  puts "Nope"
end
```

Because `ARGV` is an array, and [`Array#include?(ob)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) returns `true`, if the `ob` found inside the array.

Comment: Derp. Dropping the "== true" solved my issue. I was typing faster than thinking I guess.

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers so far are right in that it's a precedence problem.

Here are a couple helpful notes, the first of which has already been touched on:

1. You don't need `== true`, since the `include?` method already returns true or false.
2. For parsing command-line arguments, you might find it more intuitive to use a library like [Trollop](http://trollop.rubyforge.org). Using Trollop, your example could be done like this:

   ```
   require 'trollop'
   opts = Trollop::options do
     opt :verbose, "Run verbosely"  # (-v is created automatically from this)
   end

   if opts[:v] 
     puts "yes" 
   else
     puts "no"
   end
   ```

(EDIT: See also the Tin Man's answer re: optparse)